# TensorFlow: how to start the Profiler

Tags: tensorflow, profiling

I want to profile my model. This is a tutorial on how to do it: https://towardsdatascience.com/howto-profile-tensorflow-1a49fb18073d. But I would like to use the TensorFlow profiler, as shown in https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/blob/master/tensorflow/core/profiler/README.md#quick-start. According to this post, the following code should start the profiler:

```
# When using high-level API, session is usually hidden.
#
# Under the default ProfileContext, run a few hundred steps.
# The ProfileContext will sample some steps and dump the profiles
# to files. Users can then use command line tool or Web UI for
# interactive profiling.
with tf.contrib.tfprof.ProfileContext('/tmp/train_dir') as pctx:
  # High level API, such as slim, Estimator, etc.
  train_loop()

bazel-bin/tensorflow/core/profiler/profiler \
--profile_path=/tmp/train_dir/profile_xx
tfprof> op -select micros,bytes,occurrence -order_by micros

# To be open sourced...
bazel-bin/tensorflow/python/profiler/profiler_ui \
--profile_path=/tmp/profiles/profile_1
```

I generated the file profile_100 and located the directory profiler. So this is what I typed in my terminal:

```
bazel-/Users/mencia/anaconda/envs/tensorflow_py36/lib/python3.6/site-packages/tensorflow/profiler \ 
--profile_path=~/tmp/train_dir/profile_100
```

This raised the following error:

```
-bash: 
bazel-/Users/mencia/anaconda/envs/tensorflow_py36/lib/python3.6/site- packages/tensorflow/profiler: No such file or directory
```

My directory profiler contains:

```
__init__.py
__pycache__
```

But according to the above code, there should be

```
profiler/profiler
```

Which I don't have.

What do I do to start the Profiler?

Answer (score 2):

You have to build the profiler first. Clone the TensorFlow repo (`git clone https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow.git`) and run `bazel build --config opt tensorflow/core/profiler:profiler` in the root directory.